# How do I use user typing functionality in node.js chat app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I'm trying to make a `node.js` chat app using `socket.io`, I want to add a functionality that "user is typing" and online users functionality. How do I add this?

Comment: [Handling Authentication and Authorization with Node](https://medium.com/quick-code/handling-authentication-and-authorization-with-node-7f9548fedde8)

Comment: Good job completely changing the question you were asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can detect in your app when someone started typing (onChange from a input field) and then broadcast a message to socket.io that the given user is typing a message and process that accordingly.